# multiple fileappenders in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have to put the log info in two separate log files based on some condition.how to do that.
here is my logging.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.File=${catalina.home}/logs/std.log
log4j.appender.stdout.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.stdout.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c] %p - %m%n


log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/demo.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c] %p - %m%n
```

Comment: for some java class i want to print the log in a.log for others i want to print the logs in b.log

Answer (score 10):

You can define multiple appenders and assign java packages to the appenders. In the example below all classes in `com.mycorp.web` will log to web.log at `DEBUG` level and classes in `com.mycorp.db` will log to db.log at `INFO` level.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, weblogger, dblogger

#Define which packages use which appenders
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.web=DEBUG,weblogger
log4j.logger.com.mycorp.db=INFO,dblogger

#Ensure the logs don't add to each other
log4j.additivity.com.mycorp.web=false
log4j.additivity.com.mycorp.db=false

#Define web appender
log4j.appender.weblogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.weblogger.File=/var/log/myapp/web.log
log4j.appender.weblogger.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.weblogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.weblogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.weblogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m %n

#Define db appender
log4j.appender.dblogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dblogger.File=/var/log/myapp/db.log
log4j.appender.dblogger.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.dblogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.dblogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dblogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m %n
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Helped a lot. Been fiddling around wih that the whole day …

Answer (score 0):

Based on your condition, you can grab different loggers.

```
Logger x = predicate() ? Logger.getLogger("wombat") : Logger.getLogger("other");
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html (Search for "wombat" for the relevant code.)

Comment: Logger logg=Logger.getLogger("stdout"); logg.info("some text")        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("R");  logger.info("test") but both are printing to the same log files

Comment: @Lalchand maybe you miss the `log4j.additivity` part? I know this post is old and you probably solved it already. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want different file for some logger, you should write something like this:

```
log4j.logger.LOGGER_ONE=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.LOGGER_TWO=WARN, R
```